# XMLHttpRequest - response em branco

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Tenho um arquivo no servidor que, caso encontre o login e senha informados, retorna `1` ou `0` caso nada seja achado. Porém, não estou conseguindo receber essa informação usando `XMLHttpRequest`. No PHP, uso `echo (json_encode($))` para passar o valor, mas não sei como pegar esse valor.

Aqui está meu Javascript:

```
function logar()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://clleyton.hostoi.com/form_login.php/?login=" + document.getElementById("login").value + "&senha=" + document.getElementById("senha").value;
    console.log(url);
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)
            {

                console.log(request.responseText);
                console.log(request.response);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Parece haver um erro de formação da URL:

`var url = "...hostoi.com/form_login.php/?login="...`

Provavelmente o que você quer usar é `form_login.php?login` tente tirar o `/`

Answer (score 0):

Confesso que não tenho experiência com XMLHttpRequest e não tenho como lhe dar uma resposta exata sobre como resolver o problema da forma que precisa. Mas recomendo a utilização do [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) para comunicação entre `client <-> server`.

De forma simples irá conseguir fazer o request (`GET`) que precisa e controlar a resposta através de `Promises`.

Sei que pode parecer demais utilizar um polyfill para seu problema, mas em contexto geral acho válido avaliar que se trata de uma tecnologia nova e com especificação nativa no javascript. Estará apenas antecipando o que um dia será comum no dia a dia. Bem mais elegante e simples do que esse tal de  `XMLHttpRequest` ;)